# why $(“img”)[0] doen't work?

Tags: jquery

code:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" alt="This is 1 test.">

<img src="image2.jpg" alt="This is 2 test">
```

jquery code:

```
 alert($('img')[0].attr('alt'));
```

why there is not pop up a box, and shows `This is 1 test.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To directly answer your question:

It doesn't work because `[0]` returns a native DOM Element of the selector, which doesn't have a method called `.attr()`. You need to use `.eq(index)`, which basically extracts out the `index`'th element of the elements represented by `$()`. Note that `$()` returns an *array-like* object and not an array per-se (thus `[0]` doesn't work out of the box)

Comment: There's no such thing as a `DOMElement`. (Did you mean: DOM element?)

Comment: all along I thought it has one :s, thanks @minitech for the new knowledge :)

Comment: is there a way to know $() returns an array-like object and not an array. thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) for this:

```
 alert($('img').eq(0).attr('alt'));
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("img")[0]` returns the raw DOM element.  You want the jQuery object that wraps the DOM element.

use `$("img").eq(0)` to get the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

`$('img')[0]` returns HTMLElement Object, not jquery Object, so it doesn't have the method `.attr`.
If you want to use it, you should do `$('img')[0].getAttribute('alt')`.

Or you still want the jquery object,
You could use `$('img').first().attr('alt')`.

Comment: thank you. how do i know which element returns HTMLElement Object or jquery Object,

Comment: You could use the debug console to check it.

Comment: how to use  the debug console, could you give more detail of it.many thanks

Comment: If you use firefox, then it is firebug. Or Chrome then it is Chrome debug tools, Even IE has debug tools.

Comment: i am using firebug. but i don't know how to check it in the console window.

Comment: `console.log($('img')[0]);` then watch the console.